# snake can't move on the very edge of the canvas in my JS snake game

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I'm making a snake game in JS. The original problem i was working on was trying to get the game to stop running by using `clearInterval(game);` once the snake head makes contact with the edge of the canvas. Once I figured that out it created a new problem. You can't ride the snake on the edge of the canvas. This is a problem because the food will generate on the edge sometimes. Any ideas, I'm stumped. Thanks:)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 768;
canvas.height = 512;

//now put those dimensions into variables
const cvsW = canvas.width;
const cvsH = canvas.height;

//create snake unit
const unit = 16;

//create snake array
let snake = [{x: cvsW/2, y: cvsH/2}];

//delcare global variable to hold users direction
let direction;

//create food object
let food = {
 x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
 y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
}

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
 //set direction
 if (e.keyCode == 37 && direction != 'right') direction = 'left';
 else if (e.keyCode == 38 && direction != 'down') direction = 'up';
 else if (e.keyCode == 39 && direction != 'left') direction = 'right';
 else if (e.keyCode == 40 && direction != 'up') direction = 'down';
}

function draw() {
 //refresh canvas
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvsW, cvsH);
 //draw snake
 for(let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, unit, unit);
 }

 //grab head position
 let headX = snake[0].x;
 let headY = snake[0].y;

 //check if snake hit wall
 if(headX <= 0 || headY <= 0 || headX >= (cvsW-unit) || headY >= (cvsH-unit)) {
  clearInterval(runGame);
 }

 //posistion food on board
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fillRect(food.x, food.y, unit, unit);

 //send the snake in chosen direction
 if(direction == 'left') headX -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'up') headY -= unit;
 else if(direction == 'right') headX += unit;
 else if(direction == 'down') headY += unit;

 //create new head
 let newHead = {x: headX, y: headY}

 if(headX == food.x && headY == food.y) {
  //create new food position
   food = {
   x : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsW/unit)-1)+1)*unit,
   y : Math.floor(Math.random()*((cvsH/unit)-1)+1)*unit
  }
  
  //add 3 units to the snake
  snake.unshift(newHead);
  snake.unshift(newHead);
  snake.unshift(newHead);
 }
 else {
  //remove tail
  snake.pop();
 }

 //add head to snake
 snake.unshift(newHead);
}

//run game engine
let runGame = setInterval(draw, 70);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake Game</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;  
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you are using an interval to run the box movement. When you `clearInterval`, you never set it again, so the drawing does not occur. You should consider not using an interval at all. I would use a `keypress` event, which should continue to fire while the key is pressed.

Comment: @PHPglue Sorry but I don't really understand this answer, maybe it could be detailed more, sorry I'm a slow learner and kinda need things spelled out for me. I've been following some tutorials to make this and both of them use SetInterval to run the game. I don't know how that would look without it? care to elaborate